Cast struct type to array and preserve hierarchy in schema
I have this  piece of dummy data.
data = {
    "return": {
        "a": {
            "b": [
                {
                    "id": 1111,
                    "ts1": "1990-03-11T00:00:00+01:00",
                    "ts2": "1990-03-28T00:00:00+02:00",
                    "c": "C",
                    "d": 112,
                    "name": "Name",
                    "obj": {
                        "obj2": {
                            "id": 111,
                            "col1": True,
                            "col2": 1,
                            "col3": 2,
                            "col4": 4097
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

The schema of DataFrame look like this:

I want to cast the obj2 structure to be an ArrayType. The result should like this with preserved hierarchy:
data = {
    "return": {
        "a": {
            "b": [
                {
                    "id": 1111,
                    "ts1": "1990-03-11T00:00:00+01:00",
                    "ts2": "1990-03-28T00:00:00+02:00",
                    "c": "C",
                    "d": 112,
                    "name": "Name",
                    "obj": {
                        "obj2": [ 
                          {
                            "id": 111,
                            "col1": True,
                            "col2": 1,
                            "col3": 2,
                            "col4": 4097
                          }
                       ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

I could cast this object to be an array type

but due to usage of withColumn(), spark added this array to the end. I want to replace old nested structure with new one with ArrayType.
I've heard about usage of withFields(), tried to use it, but I didn't succeed. Could tell me if it is possible to change data type of structure and preserve its hierarchy?
Thanks in advance!
